# Setting a value in a text field using selenium. selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element:

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm new to the Web scraping stuff and python. My task is to set the value for text box name "rcdate" for the mention URL by using selenium. Then scrape the values which were filtered. when it's run it gives this exception. This is the code which I try to run

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 


browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("http://www.irrigation.gov.lk/index.php?option=com_reservoirdata&Itemid=255&lang=en")

wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'rcdate')))

browser.find_element_by_tag_name("rcdate").send_keys("2018-10-01")
```

Then Error Msg is

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: rcdate
```

Html

```
<input type="text" name="rcdate" id="rcdate" value="2018-10-11">
```

Comment: Post the relevant html.

Comment: Text box HTML  `<input type="text" name="rcdate" id="rcdate" value="2018-10-11">`

Comment: is there any tag with the name "rcdate" if not then dont use line browser.find_element_by_tag_name("rcdate").send_keys("2018-10-01")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get an *ERROR 403 - FORBIDDEN* while trying to access the url `http://www.irrigation.gov.lk/index.php?option=com_reservoirdata&Itemid=255&lang=en`

However, once you locate the element and moving forward as you are trying to invoke `send_keys()` method, so instead of expected_conditions as `presence_of_element_located()` you should use **`element_to_be_clickable()`** as follows:

- `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#rcdate"))).send_keys("2018-10-01")
  ```
- `ID`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "rcdate"))).send_keys("2018-10-01")
  ```

Comment: is there are any way to replace the existing text box value . Then I need to pass the value from the code.

Comment: While this code might work, described solution has nothing to do with real problem: it's not about waithing for element to be clickable, but wrong selector strategy, so other two answers seem to be more useful

Comment: @Haz Of-coarse it is possible to _...replace the existing text box value with a new value..._ using the _execute_script()_ method. Feel free to raise a new question with your new requirement. Contributors will be happy to help you out.

Comment: @DebanjanB yes sure. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
find_element_by_name() # locate element by the "name" attribute
```

Not to be confused with

```
find_element_by_tag_name() # locate element by the element tag ("input" in this case)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing wrong at this line, So
using this line,

```
browser.find_element_by_tag_name("rcdate").send_keys("2018-10-01")
```

make no sense, as there is no such tag present and you are using by tag name "rcdate",

use either,

```
browser.find_element_by_id("rcdate").send_keys("2018-10-01")
browser.find_element_by_name("rcdate").send_keys("2018-10-01")
```

or

I hope this might help you,

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 


browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("http://www.irrigation.gov.lk/index.php?option=com_reservoirdata&Itemid=255&lang=en")

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#rcdate"))).send_keys("2018-10-01")
```

Comment: Thanks @Ashish for the help. It's working. I need replace the existing text box value . Then I need to pass the value from the code. Is there any mechanism for that.